# How to anchor a fixed-height <div> to the bottom right of a <td> without intruding into content above?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

**1) The Basic Problem.**

I know this is a long statement of a problem, but please bear with me. The problem's kind of simple, but it takes me a bit to set it up for you.

I have a 5x7 table representing 5 time slots in the day with 7 classrooms in each slot. The `<td>`s have a complex inner HTML structure housing the class title, and instructor's name, together with a class desrciption and instructor bio that populate modal dialogs that popup when the title or name are clicked.

I need to add a `<div>` (a real-time registration counter) anchored to the `<td>`'s bottom right without it intruding upward into content above it.

**2) The Problem Setup.**

The HTML for a typical `<td>` looks like this.

```
          <td id="x0900A">                  <!-- 0900 room A -->
            <div class="classTitle"></div>
            <div class="classDescrip"></div>
            <div class="instructor"></div>
            <div class="gender"></div>
            <div class="instructorBio"></div>
            <div class="instructorImg"></div>
            <div id="x0900A-roomCount" class="roomCount">
              <div class="regis">registered</div>
              <div class="cap">capacity</div>
            </div>
          </td>
```

The title, instrucrtor name, and room count show in the cell. The other `<div>`s are `display {hidden;}`. Their content populates modal dialogs that popup on a click on title or name.

With this CSS, I can lock `.roomCount` to the bottom right.

```
    td {
      position: relative;
    }
    .roomCount{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      tex-align: right;
    }
```

But, in some cells, its text directly abuts the instructor name above it. In others, not. When it does, the name is illegible.

The table data is on an Amazon Web Services server. With JavaScript, on each page load, I dynamically retrieve it and build the table.

You can see it all at work at [this pen](https://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/qzBdJw) on CodePen.

**3) I Need A Solution That Doesn't Restructure The HTML.**

I need to keep `.roomCount` from abutting the instructor name as it does in some cells.

I wouldn't mind restructuring the HTML but that I stupidly wrote the JavaScript dependent upon the elements' positions in the `<td>`. (It was my first time. What can I say?) I'd have to rewrite the JS, which I also wouldn't mind doing, but that I haven't time before I have to take the site live.

So, I need a solution without restructuring the HTML elements in the `<td>`s.

**4) Any Help?**

Any help?

Thanks ever so much for reading this far. Your help will be greatly appreciated. In fact, if you can solve it, I'll polish your shoes for six months. (I hope you wear sneakers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brutally hacky way is to increase the size of the bottom padding or margin on the instructor's name.

```
.schedule p {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}
```

That will put more room under the course title though. If you want it under only the instructor, change the instructor css block to

```
.schedule p.instructor {
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-align: right;
    color: #00b8b8;
}
```

The `margin` and `padding` properties on your `.instructor` rule are currently being ignored because `.schedule p` has higher specificity.

Comment: Ah, specificity! I know about it but neglected to check. So simple when it's pointed out. Thanks ever so much for taking the time to plod through the CSS and spot that. I went with adding `!important` to the `margin` and `padding` instructions in `.instructor`. It seems simpler to me, though it may not be good coding practice. Thanks again. It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `.classTitle` having different height because the length of content is different. Height of all td in a same row are the same. When `.classTitle` takes up more space,  `.roomCount` is left with less space at the bottom. And with `position: absolute`, it 'overlaps with `.instructor`

You can try adding fixed height to `.classTitle` and `.instructor`. This way, you can remove the `position: absolute` from `.roomCount`.

```
.classTitle {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #00b8b8;
    height: 4em;     /* Added Sample Height */
}

.instructor {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-align: right;
    color: #00b8b8;
    height: 1.2em;     /* Added Sample Height */
}

.roomCount {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    /* right: 0; */
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to go through the CSS. I went with @dgrogan's answer because it's simpler. Thanks again. I really appreciate your time.